# wso2 esb error on multi threading

Tags: multithreading, wso2-esb

we have the following setup

1. Sending a message from one queue to another queue.
2. The message will be transformed from text to xml.

With the single consumer(thread), It is working fine.

When We have 10 Concurrent Consumers. we are getting the following exception. This problem happens only when we dump around 500 messages and then start the wso2 ESB server.

Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at pil.pershing.transform.esb.mediator.TransformNewXmlMediator.mediate(TransformNewXmlMediator.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:78)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:588)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 16 more

Comment: Though we have used reentrantlock as it is used in your Mediator class. Still we are facing the same issue. Can you please suggest any other option.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a custom mediator "pil.pershing.transform.esb.mediator.TransformNewXmlMediator". Perhaps this one is not thread safe : the concurrent consumers calls "mediate" on the same instance of TransformNewXmlMediator, verify if your code is reentrant